# Can't Sort HasMany Relationship in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I know there are many questions regarding the Sorting Properties in Yii2. I'm a beginner in using this framework and I've exhausted all the reference that I can be found on the internet.

So for the first Part.

I try using the orderBy method on the Controller but can't seem to work it either.

My controller part uses this code:

```
$saleModel = Sales::find()->with([
    'customer',
    'salesItems',
    'salesItems.item'
])->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```

Now I have a Model called Sales on this model I have a hasMany relations with SalesItems model.

```
public function getSalesItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SalesItems::className(), ['sale_id' => 'id'])
}
```

I have tried sorting this SalesItems model using the 'item_id' that can be found in this Model and it is working.

```
public function getSalesItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SalesItems::className(), ['sale_id' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['item_id' => SORT_DESC]);
}
```

But what I want is to sort my SalesItems thru an another connected table/model that is connected via the item_id column in the sales items model.

On this case, I have another table called items which have an ID column this part is where they join `['id' =>'item_id']`.

Overall, I want to sort my SalesItems based on the items.name.

My SQL Statement should be like this:

```
SELECT sales.id , sales.customer_id, sales_items.item_id, 
sales_items.sale_id, items.name FROM sales
INNER JOiN sales_items ON sales_items.sale_id = sales.id
INNER JOIN items ON sales_items.item_id = items.id WHERE sales.id =6374
ORDER BY items.name ASC;
```

I run this SQL Statemend on DB and successfully retrieve the results the way I wanted it to.

Here is also the table Schema:

[image]

Hope someone can understand what I've been trying to do.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to debug it? If you are using PhpStorm, it has a Debugger which is really good. When you do that it will show you SQL query generated from that PHP code and then you can compare to the one u presented here.

Comment: so you just want to transform this raw query? and is this query you have provided gives the correct results?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yeah. I'm getting the right result on MySQL when I run this in the database. I just don't have the idea on how to recreate this thru a model in Yii2. 

Because when I render this 'Sales::` model array I want it to be sorted by the 'item.name' field which can be found on the 'Items' model.

Comment: check if **[THIS](https://pastebin.com/0eh3fKCd)** is what you were looking for , will add as answer if it works

Comment: Hi Im getting an error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'si.item_id' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `s`.`id`, `s`.`customer_id`, `si`.`item_id`, `si`.`sale_id`, `i`.`name` FROM `sales` `s` WHERE `s`.`id`='6374'


And just another question? Why do we need a select statement if all the customer, salesItems has their own model?

Comment: see the answer below with a few changes to the query it should work correctly now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following query with `joinWith` to achieve what you want, and you need one more column in the list to be selected `i.id` otherwise it would only show one item.

```
$saleModel = Sales::find()->alias('s')
    ->select('s.id, s.customer_id, si.item_id, si.sale_id, i.name, i.id')
    ->joinWith(
        [
            'customer c',
            'salesItems si',
            'salesItems.item i'
        ], false, 'INNER JOIN'
    )
    ->where(['s.id' => 1])->orderBy('i.name ASC')->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: Hi,  I've try this method but now I'm getting an error with my View. 

I can't access the $saleModel object.

The error is this: Trying to get property 'customer' of non-object

While in my view: $saleModel->customer->company_name

Comment: I use something like this in reference with your code:
 $saleModel = Sales::find()->alias('s')->joinWith([
                   'customer c',
                   'salesItems si',
                   'salesItems.item i'
               ], false, 'INNER JOIN')
              ->where(['s.id' => $id])
              ->orderBy('i.name ASC')
              ->one();

I was able to get it working but the array is not ordered by Name

Comment: looks like the schema is different than what i though can you share the schema diagram into your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try viaTable function of ActiveQuery:

```
public function getSalesItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SalesItems::className(), ['sale_id' => 'id'])
         ->viaTable('items', ['id' => 'item_id'])
         ->orderBy(['items.name' => SORT_ASC]);
}
```

Comment: Hi @rakhmatov. I try this method but I always get an error:
Getting unknown property: app\models\Sales::item_id

Comment: Please also take note that the Sales model has no 'item_id' field. 

The item_id field can be found in the SalesItems model. 

The joins are like this Sales.Id = SalesItems.sales_id, while to access the Items.name property SalesItems.item_id = Items.id

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes(they've worked on my localhost):

In a controller:

```
$sales = Sales::find()->with([
            'customer',
            'salesItems',
            'salesItems.item'
        ])->where(['id' => 2])->asArray()->one();
```

or

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;

        $query = $db->createCommand("SELECT sales.id , sales.customer_id, sales_items.item_id, 
                    sales_items.sale_id, items.name FROM sales
                    INNER JOiN sales_items ON sales_items.sale_id = sales.id
                    INNER JOIN items ON sales_items.item_id = items.id WHERE sales.id =2
                    ORDER BY items.name ASC;")->queryAll();
```

In the SalesItems model:

```
<?php
//...
class SalesItems extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
//...
public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Items::className(), ['id' => 'item_id']);
    }
//...
}
```

In the Sales model:

```
<?php
//...
class Sales extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
//...
public function getSalesItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SalesItems::className(), ['sale_id' => 'id'])->orderBy(['item_id' => SORT_DESC]);
    }

    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Customers::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Active record:

```
     $query = Sales::find()->alias('sl')
        ->select('sl.id, sl.customer_id, si.item_id, si.sale_id, itm.name')
        ->joinWith('salesItem AS si', true)
        ->joinwith('salesItem.item AS itm')
        ->where(['si.id' => $id])
        ->orderBy(['itm.name' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Then you can use any of the provided methods to retrieve the query results. or if you would like to test your query use:

```
$sql = $query->createCommand()->sql;
```

To see if it matches your raw query.

Comment: Why not create a database view ?

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use the relationships feature in most frameworks save for laravel which is restraining in this feature.

Understanding your question and the ERDs so presented, I will suggest a simplified answer for this specific issue

I note that ***`si.sale_id`*** joins to ***`s.id`*** and hence are numerically equal for the relationship to hold

Here, therefore, is my preferred solution

```
/**
 * 
 * @param integer $sales_id sales id
 * @return \frontend\models\SalesItems[] models
 */
public function getSalesItems($sales_id) {

    $s = \frontend\models\Sales::tableName();

    $si = \frontend\models\SalesItems::tableName();

    $i = \frontend\models\Items::tableName();

    return $this
                ->select('s.id, s.customer_id, si.item_id, si.sale_id, i.name')->from("$si si")
                ->leftJoin("$s s", "'$sales_id' = s.id")
                ->leftJoin("$i i", "si.item_id = i.id")
                ->where("si.sale_id = '$sales_id'")
                ->orderBy('i.name asc')
                ->all();
}
```

Run this in the SalesItems model class

Please introduce the following two attributes in the ***`SalesItems`*** model class only (not database table table) as follows

```
class SalesItems extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    // copy line below into SalesItems class
    public $name, $customer_id;

}
```

I believe it is highly optimized this way

Hope it helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i know its been a long time you ask this question.
i think sorting for 1:n relationship has some work to be complete or it has some secret we can't discover.
i hope on yii3 it would be solved .

but for your problem i  copy my code that is much common to yours.
{{{{info: my specification_value belong to CAR TIRE parameter}}}}

i have 1:n relation ( product_tbl  1:n  productSpecificationValue_tbl()  )
each product has many specification and every specifiaction has value.
i wanna sort my gridView among SPECIFICATION_VALUES

so i write separate relation for every single specification_value i wanna sort by it.
i need 3 of them so i write these 3 relation:

```php
<?php
 public function getProductTreadWidth()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductSpecification::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->where(['specification_id' => 2]);

    }
    public function getProductAspectRatio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductSpecification::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->where(['specification_id' => 3]);
    }
    public function getProductDiameter()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductSpecification::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->where(['specification_id' => 5]);
    }
?>
```

then i take GET['sort'] parameter value
if it is productTreadWith i make my DataProvider  join into that
if it is productAspectRatio i make my DataProvider join into that one and so on...
Like the code below:

```php
if(Yii::$app->request->get()['sort'] == 'productTreadWidth.value_en' || Yii::$app->request->get()['sort'] == '-productTreadWidth.value_en') {
                $joinTable = 'productTreadWidth';
            } elseif(Yii::$app->request->get()['sort'] == 'productAspectRatio.value_en' || Yii::$app->request->get()['sort'] == '-productAspectRatio.value_en') {
                $joinTable = 'productAspectRatio';
            } elseif(Yii::$app->request->get()['sort'] == 'productDiameter.value_en' || Yii::$app->request->get()['sort'] == '-productDiameter.value_en') {
                $joinTable = 'productDiameter';
            } else {
                $joinTable = 'productSpecificationsValuesIndexBySpecificationId';
            }
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => Product::find()->joinWith(['brand', 'family', $joinTable ], true, 'LEFT JOIN')->where(['availability_id' => 1]),
           ]);

         $dataProvider->setSort([
                'attributes' => [
                    'productTreadWidth.value_en' => [
                        'asc' => ['value_en' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['value_en' => SORT_DESC],
                        'label' => 'Tread Width',
                    ],

                    'productAspectRatio.value_en' => [
                        'asc' => ['value_en' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['value_en' => SORT_DESC],
                        'label' => 'Aspect Ratio',
                    ],
                    'productDiameter.value_en' => [
                        'asc' => ['value_en' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['value_en' => SORT_DESC],
                        'label' => 'Diameter',
                    ],
                   
                ],
            ]);
```

and for gridView i use this attributes:

```php
<?php
echo GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    [
                        'attribute' => 'brand.name_en',
                        'label' => 'Brand'

                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'family.name_en',
                        'label' => 'Model',
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'productTreadWidth.value_en',
                        'label' => Yii::t('app' , 'Tire Width'),
                        'content' => function($model){
                            return $model->productTreadWidth['value_en'];
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'productAspectRatio.value_en',
                        'label' => Yii::t('app' , 'Aspect Ratio'),
                        'content' => function($model){
                            return $model->productAspectRatio['value_en'];
                        }
                    ],
                ]
         ]);
?>
```

now you can sort which attributes you like